# Fixed element width vs visual width

Tags: html, css

I encountered an issue where an item did not center properly inside of a fixed element. While debugging around I found something that I don't fully understand.

Checkout this code snippet:

```js
const fixedRect = window.fixed.getBoundingClientRect();
const nonFixedRect = window.nonFixed.getBoundingClientRect();

const element = document.createElement("div");
element.style = "margin-top: 20vh; text-align: center;";
element.innerHTML = `Viewport Width: ${window.innerWidth.toFixed(2)}px<br>NonFixed Width: ${nonFixedRect.width.toFixed(2)}px<br>Fixed Width: ${fixedRect.width.toFixed(2)}px`;

document.querySelector(".content").appendChild(element);
```

```css
html, body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20vw;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 20vw;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#nonFixed {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div id="nonFixed">
      <div class="center"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="fixed">
      <div class="center"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The calculated width of the fixed element is the viewport width (which is expected for fixed elements). However, the actual element is only as wide as the parent container. Shouldn't the calculated width and the actual width be equal?

Comment: Well now I see what you are asking. It's a good chance to start learning how to debug using browser inspection tools.

Answer (score 0):

It only seems to be as wide but the bar is wider than you can see, it's just overflowing out of the viewport.

```js
const fixedRect = window.fixed.getBoundingClientRect();
const nonFixedRect = window.nonFixed.getBoundingClientRect();

const element = document.createElement("div");
element.style = "margin-top: 20vh; text-align: center;";
element.innerHTML = `Viewport Width: ${window.innerWidth.toFixed(2)}px<br>NonFixed Width: ${nonFixedRect.width.toFixed(2)}px<br>Fixed Width: ${fixedRect.width.toFixed(2)}px`;

document.querySelector(".content").appendChild(element);
```

```css
html, body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20vw;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 20vw;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#nonFixed {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-10vw, 0);
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div id="nonFixed">
      <div class="center"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="fixed">
      <div class="center"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the example, if you translate have the wodth of the side bar, both div are centered but the fixed one has an extra 10vw on each side (you can only see it on the left).